# how can i select an image at random from different urls when page is refreshed in php/html no javascript

Tags: php, html

Ok so, i have this chat that lets you execute html/php script to display cool things for example

```
<font color="#38ff1a">-</font><b><font class="glitch" data-text=----Name---- color="#146eff">Name/font></b><font color="#38ff1a">-</font>
```

and i want to make a script that displays random images from a url so like i have 5 gif's and the chat updates every 5sec so what i want this script to do is pick 1 of the 5 urls that have gifs and display that that gif for 5sec and then the chat will refresh and then the script will show a different image.

I made it display 1 image but i cant make it rotate to different images. Here is the code i used for that;

And no javascript as most people who visit the site have that disabled and i don't really like javascript.

Also sorry for bad spelling :/

Comment: Not your question but the `font` tag is realllly old and deprecated. You should use an updated element and use CSS.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions when they've received a couple of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to create a function that held the gifs within an array. Then you could create a random number generator to randomly pick one of the 5 gifs within the array to display. Save the images as strings so when they are put into the HTML file they render as HTML. Just make sure your random number generator range is from 0 to 4 if there are five elements within the array. Remember arrays start at 0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JavaScript may seem a little confusing and unwanted but in some cases it's really necessary and inevitable and of course it's more efficient to use it instead of refreshing page each 5 sec.

But if you can't do anything about it and the page refreshes every 5 sec, which means a PHP script executes every 5 sec, you may use an `array` and `rand` function to get what you want. (But I think if the page refreshes automatically then it's the job of a JS script so JS is enabled, or the page won't automatically refresh.)

```
<?php $gifUrls = ['<URL#1>', '<URL#2>', '<URL#3>', '<URL#4>', '<URL#5>']; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $gifUrls[rand(0,4)]; ?>"  width=250/>
```

Or (another option without `<?php` and `?>`)

```
<?php 
$gifUrls = ['<URL#1>', '<URL#2>', '<URL#3>', '<URL#4>', '<URL#5>'];
echo '<img src="'.$gifUrls[rand(0,4)].'"  width=250/>';
?>
```

Again, it's better to use JavaScript instead of refreshing the page and if the PHP script just executes one time the only option is using JavaScript.

Comment: If the php is executed you can see a random image, If you just see the links it means the php script is not executed and is recognized as html script. So I think the only way is to use JavaScript.